# locate an element on selenium ide

Tags: html, selenium

Hello i am new for selenium IDE and i have a question about how to locate an specific element using selenium IDE.

I have HTML like following:

```
<div id="locator">
 <table class = "table-1">
 </table>
 <div class="something else">
 </div>
 <table class = "table-1">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <td>
     <div class="adder">....</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that i want to locate the div element in the second table element
Could anyone figure me out how to do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use the pseudo class `:nth-of-type`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table.table-1:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td > div.adder"));
```

If you use the Selenium IDE, then use

```
css=table.table-1:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td > div.adder
```

See the [Selenium IDE documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-css).

Of course you could also use XPath instead of css (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-xpath).

> the css selector locator supports all css1, css2 and css3 selectors
>   except namespace in css3, some pseudo classes(:nth-of-type,
>   :nth-last-of-type, :first-of-type, :last-of-type, :only-of-type,
>   :visited, :hover, :active, :focus, :indeterminate) and pseudo
>   elements(::first-line, ::first-letter, ::selection, ::before, ::after)

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i  am using selenium IDE - a basic one :). Do you know how can i do it with selenium IDE? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is still not working on my side, but documentation from you is very useful, i will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

> driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#locator table:nth-of-type(2)
>   div.adder"));

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i am not using selenium webdriver and i am using selenium IDE - a basic one :). Do you know how can i do it with selenium IDE? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the selector mentioned above is wrong.  CSS doesn't support some pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.  The unsupported ones are listed below.

`css=table.table-1:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td > div.adder`

> 6.7. CSS
>
> The CSS locator strategy uses CSS selectors to find the elements in the page. Selenium supports CSS 1 through 3 selectors syntax excepted CSS3 namespaces and the following:

```
pseudo-classes       pseudo-elements

:nth-of-type          ::first-line

:nth-last-of-type     ::first-letter

:first-of-type        ::selection

:last-of-type         ::before

:only-of-type         ::after

:visited    

:hover

:active

:focus

:indeterminate
```